# I Used A Laptop Charger With Wrong Polarity (AC)

Tags: laptop, battery, power

I bought a new laptop charger and whenever I plugged it into my laptop my mouse would go all crazy, move around by itself, freeze up etc... Which obviously indicated that the charger I got was incompatible with my Laptop. So I looked on the base of the new charger and noticed that the polarity was not the same as the original laptop charger.... I've read that using a charger with an incorrect/incompatible polarity can fry a device very easily, which is what's worrying me.

It appears as though my Laptop is completely fine, but my question is, is there a possibility that any circuitry/anything within my laptop got fried/ruined? Or should I be fine? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible?  Yes. Im surprised it even worked.  I have a feeling it was actually running off the battery, not the AC.

The fact the laptop appears to be working fine is a very good sign.  However, there is no way to know if anything was damaged without testing.  If your laptop has a diagnostic utility or partition, I would run through it, just to be safe.  However, I think you are in the clear if there was no obvious damage.

Comment: The only thing that can be said on top of this is that over-voltage and reverse-voltage protection could have been designed in by a conscientious engineer and done the job of protecting the system. Plugging it in and having the protection attempting to protect while the system was running could cause minor blips in the voltage in the rest of the system resulting in oddness. Some manufacturers wouldn't have bothered with the protection and saved themselves some small change and left it to customers to use manufacturer approved chargers or risk having to buy a new laptop.